# Deploy Flask app on AWS EC2

Tags: python, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, flask

I'm trying to deploy a simple Flask app on EC2.
Everything works fine, but when I try to access to my site I get a 404 error that says:

*The requested URL /flaskapp.py/flaskapp.wsgi/ was not found on this server.*

flaskapp.py code:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "hello"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

flaskapp.wsgi:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/html/flaskapp')

from flaskapp import app as application
```

And finally the file 000-default.conf

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost 
    ServerName myServerHostname
    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    WSGIDaemonProcess flaskapp threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/flaskapp/flaskapp.wsgi

<Directory flaskapp>
    WSGIProcessGroup flaskapp
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        # This directive allows us to have apache2's default start page
                # in /apache2-default/, but still have / go to the right place
                #RedirectMatch ^/$ /apache2-default/
    </Directory>



    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
    ServerSignature On


</VirtualHost>
```

Is this code wrong? 
What can I do to fix it?
Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I "solved" this problem using Nginx instead of Apache.
I used the sample configuration that I found in the Flask documentation pdf with gunicorn web server, easiest way!

Comment: Well, that's not the right answer to the question, is it?

Comment: Of course it's not, just a workaround, I'll edit my answer to be more clear

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to run a basic Flask app om EC2 :

1) application = app = Flask(--name--underscore as usual)
....
....
application.run()

2) save the file as "application.py"

3) Zip the project with requirement.txt and upload the zip file through AWS EB concole.

It will run.